# how to generate serial number for each selection in combobox in excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With ComboBox1.Value
        Dim a, b As String
        Dim i, j, k, l, x, q, m, temp As Long
        a = ComboBox1.Text
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, Range("A1:A1000"), 0)
        j = Cells(i, 2)
        l = j * 1000
        For q = 2 To 100
            For m = 2 To 100
                If Cells(q, m).Value < 0 Then
                    k = m
                End If
            Next
        Next
        x = l
        If Cells(i, GC).Value = temp Then
            Click = Click + 1
        Else
            Click = 0
        End If
        Cells(i, GC) = x + Click
        TextBox1.Text = x + Click
        temp = Cells(i, GC).Value
    End With
    GC = GC + 1
```

it's a link of snapping what the problem of coming,

[image: https://plus.google.com/100336580781932243792/posts/VHb18Hv6pTt?pid=6207264542909974946&oid=100336580781932243792]

for more description

Above screen short presents the issue. what we want to achieve is that when a user select a value in column “A” the logic provides a value which contains predefined value derived from column “B” and a system generated serial number starting from “000”.

Say – When user selects from column “A” – PP , The system will get the corresponding value from column ”B” - 210 , and should also generate a serial number starting from “000”, and concatenate the value and should provide “210000” for the user.

When the user selects from column “A” – KK , , The system will get the corresponding value from column ”B” - 103 , and should also generate a serial number starting from “000”, and concatenate the value and should provide “103000” for the user.

When again the user selects column “A” – PP ,The system will get the corresponding value from column ”B” - 210 , and should also generate a serial number starting from “001”, and concatenate the value and should provide “210001” for the user. As the serial number ”000”, is already consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in UserForm1 module

```
Option Explicit

Private ur As Range

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim c As Range, co As Range

    Set c = getLastID
    Set co = c.Offset(, -1)

    If Len(co) > 0 Then c = co + 1 Else c = ur.Cells(c.Row, 2) * 1000
    Me.TextBox1.Text = c
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = getLastID.Offset(, -1)
End Sub

Private Function getLastID() As Range
    Dim sel As String, lc As Long, cr As Long

    sel = Me.ComboBox1.Text
    If Len(sel) = 0 Then sel = ur.Cells(ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count, 1)

    cr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sel, ur.Columns(1), 0)
    lc = ur.Cells(cr, ur.Column + ur.Columns.Count + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If lc < 5 Then lc = lc + 2
    Set getLastID = ur.Cells(cr, lc + 1)
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ur = Worksheets(1).UsedRange
End Sub
```

---

to generate a serial number starting from ID in column B * 1,000, or increment the last ID

---

[image]